# aws sts assume-role did not exit successfully ... Cannot find module

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, serverless, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to deploy an AWS lambda using serverless and getting an unhelpful combination of errors. I have a build.yaml file that looks like the following:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.8
    commands:
      - cd my_application/src/
      - npm ci && cd -
  build:
    commands:
      - |
        CRED=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn ${DEPLOYMENT_ROLE_ARN} --role-session-name auto-deploy-devops-to-${STAGE_NAME}-access`
```

The first command is where it breaking with the following error:

> ```
>     Command did not exit successfully CRED=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn ${DEPLOYMENT_ROLE_ARN} --role-session-name auto-deploy-devops-to-${STAGE_NAME}-access`
> ```

And I have seen and fixed a similar error before. Usually this has had to do with IAM permissions. However, higher up in the error stack trace I see the following:

> Error: Cannot find module '/root/.npm/_npx/342/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/protobufjs/scripts/postinstall'

This is where I am completely thrown. Any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the command work if you run it manually?

Comment: Are you confident that `DEPLOYMENT_ROLE_ARN` and `STAGE_NAME` have correct values?

Comment: I am confident of the env variables `DEPLOYMENT_ROLE_ARN` and `STAGE_NAME`